# Load WordPress Environment with Plugins from CLI

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to run a php script from cli which will access a WP plugin's class.

I've seen plenty ways of loading WP environment from cli, most common which I also use is

```
if( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
    die("Meant to be run from command line");
}

function find_wordpress_base_path() {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    do {
        //it is possible to check for other files here
        if( file_exists($dir."/wp-config.php") ) {
            return $dir;
        }
    } while( $dir = realpath("$dir/..") );
    return null;
}

define( 'BASE_PATH', find_wordpress_base_path()."/" );
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

However the above code will not load the plugins and if I try to access a plugin's class i get the error "**Call to undefined method**". I've also
tried running it from wp-cli using eval-file command, but again with no luck.

any ideas on how to load wordpress environment with plugins from cli ?

Comment: Duplicate of unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817192/wordpress-cli-script-and-plugin-functions-availibility